# MySQL - How to get data from 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I seem to be a little stumped... I'm trying to get data from three tables, but they're not all inter-related -- one table relates to each of the other two.

- Exams_taken

  - ID
  - exam_id
  - user_id
- Exams_available

  - ID
  - exam_name
- Users

  - ID
  - user_name

I want to create an output where I have the exam_id, exam_name, and user_name.

I thought I could figure out how to do this as a single query, but I'm lost. Is it possible? Or do I need to do a query on 'Exams_available' and then a loop with a second query to JOIN 'Exams_taken' and 'Users'?

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: you never need loops. you would join the three tables together. BTW the ID column in exams_taken table is redundant, only the other two columns are needed.

Comment: Ah, it looks like I wrote that wrong... the ID column what I need in the output, not the exam_id.

Comment: Which `ID` column. There is one of those in all 3 tables?????

Comment: Good point... the output I need is Exams_taken.ID Exams_available.exam_name Users.user_name

Answer (score 2):

If you need an output that contains `exam_id`, `exam_name` and `user_name` I can suppose that you need the Exams taken, so why not just query like this:

```
SELECT exam_id, E.exam_name, U.user_name FROM Exams_taken as ET
INNER JOIN Exams_available as E on ET.exam_id = E.exam_id
INNER JOIN Users as U on ET.user_id = U.user_id
```

Comment: Thanks... so, since I miswrote that, would it work as: 

`SELECT ID, exam_id, E.exam_name, U.user_name FROM Exams_taken as ET INNER JOIN Exams_available as E on ET.exam_id = E.exam_id
INNER JOIN Users as U on ET.user_id = U.user_id` 

- then I can just loop through to create my list of completed exams with links to the reports (using the ID)

Comment: @ScottM Yeah, that will work, just to clarify, `ID` will be the ID of `Exam_taken`

Comment: yes, that's right. Thank you so much... now I'll see if I can figure out my output! ;-)

Comment: @ScottM You're welcome, if you find my answer helpful please mark it as accepted or upvote it

Comment: Your answer is definitely helpful, but so far I'm getting "no results" even though I know all three tables have data. I'm working through it. (why does the @ with your username keep getting stripped from my responses?)

Comment: @ScottM if you have `null` values you can use `LEFT JOIN` to get results otherwise you will not get anything.

Comment: There should be no `null` values at all... but the query isn't returning any results (I put in an `if(empty($reportList) { echo "no reports" }` statement to let me know, and it's telling me "no reports"... which I know not to be true. At first I thought part of it was I had put in the wrong column names (I had simplified it some in my question here) but when I checked and made sure it was all correct, still "no reports".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101028/discussion-between-scottm-and-sgtrockermx).